# Sending User Name with DotNetOpenAuth AuthorizedTokenResponse

Tags: dotnetopenauth

I've been following the Oauth Provider example in the DotNetOpenAuth library. All going pretty good so far, have implemented a consumer and provider in two separate sites.

I am stuck on one bit, though. I want to return the userName that is usually present in HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name together with the extra data of the AuthorizedTokenResponse.
( This is similar to the way twitter add the "screen_name" in the their OAuth response )

```cs
else if ((requestAccessToken = request as AuthorizedTokenRequest) != null)
        {
            string userName = context.User.Identity.Name; // how do you tie this to the logged on user? I am soooo stupid.

            AuthorizedTokenResponse response = _oAuthServiceProvider.PrepareAccessTokenMessage(requestAccessToken);
            response.ExtraData.Add("screen_name", userName); 
            _oAuthServiceProvider.Channel.Send(response);
        }
```

So in this case HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name is null in the HttpHandler. ( I've basically adapted the HTTPHandler from the dotnetopenAuth OAuth sample. )

So I'm not sure if I am losing the plot here, but I'm lost as to how to get the authenticated users name. If it helps, the user definitely is previously logged in, and the user is set in the AuthorizeRequestToken method of the TokenManager ( mine is in memory ).

So, is there any way of getting the username using DotNetOpenAuth that is stored in AuthorizeRequestToken method before I send back the AuthorizedTokenResponse?

Comment: OK, I've solved it for now. I am not sure whether this is the *correct* answer, but after a twenty hour day, it is for now: basically I retrieved the token set for the UserAuthorizationResponse, using the VerificationCode of the AuthorizedTokenRequest and that token had the User stored against it. I am sure after some sleep there will be a better way of doing this.

Comment: It's very discouraged to send back extra user data with the response from the authorization server. Twitter does it, but it's not a good idea for most folks. It suggests you're misusing OAuth 2, which is an *authorization* protocol as if it were an *authentication* protocol. If your client wants the user's identity, the client should use OpenID. If the client wants to access the user's data at your web service, the user's identity shouldn't matter to the client.